# Pasting image in word: cursor appearing to left of pasted image

Tags: microsoft-word

When I take notes in dot point form I sometimes paste an image, press enter (to go to the next dot point) and type any notes relating to the image.

Something annoying has started happening recently:

**Whenever I paste an image in word, the cursor now reverts to the left of the image (rather than to the right of it).**

Anyone know why this has started happening? It sounds trivial but is is really annoying and distrubing my flow. It's almost like typing a sentence and then the cursor jumps back to the start of the sentence, making everything you type out of order.

E.g. image below: after pasting the image the cursor goes back to the left of the image:

[image]

One clue is that on the documents where the problem occurs, the images have this style box around them

[image]

Whilst on documents where the problem doesn't occur, the images have this style box around them

[image]

Comment: You mean the cursor moves to the left of it rather than the right of it.. You should sya that instead of using ambiguous words like front and behind when you can say left and right

Comment: Have if you try experimenting with A)left and right align  ctrl-L, ctrl-R,  and B)language direction e.g. ctrl+left shift,   ctrl-right shift.

Comment: also maybe it's not to the left of the image maybe it's on the next line and to the right of the 'e.'

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. When you say experimenting with language direction do you just mean pressure ctrl+left shift or ctrl+right shift? As doing so does not seem to have any noticeable effect.

Regarding your third comment. The curor is to the left of the image not on the next line. If it went straight to the next line it would not be an issue (and would possibly be an advantage) as it would let me keep typing down the page.

Comment: The issue here is I paste something and can't keep typing at the cursor goes back to the left (in front) of the image and anything I type will appear in front of the image resulting in 1) the image being pushed down and most importantly 2) Not being able to work down the page and everything becoming out of order.

Comment: One clue is that on the documents where the problem occurs, the images have this style box around them http://i.imgur.com/0ts6S7z.png

Whilst on documents where the problem doesnt occur, the images have this style box around then http://i.imgur.com/teCrD6w.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46388/discussion-between-barlop-and-k-feldspar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just started using Word 2016, and this problem came up. I've only found a few people comment on it, and the answers given didn't help.

I found what the difference is - If the document was saved in the Word 97-2003 format (Compatibility Mode, which I've been using for years, to ensure compatibility with my old systems and other friends), then the picture is pasted differently from using it in the .docx format.

This also explains why the original questioner noted the different style box surrounding the pictures. This is part of the difference in how modern Word programs handle images, and the graphic options change depending on Compatibility Mode or not.

If you take the same document and save as Word 97-2003 and paste, the cursor goes to the left of the image. If you save as .docx and paste, the cursor ends up at the right of the image. I guess it's time to stop using the 2003 mode as my default...